# Is it possible to keep a function running when the application is terminated in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

For example, I have a function and I want when the user deletes the application from the multitasking menu (app is killed, not running in background), the function will continue to work without affecting anything. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to keep flutter apps running in the background. Currently only works with **Android**. It achieves this functionality by running an Android foreground service in combination with a partial wake lock and disabling battery optimizations in order to keep the flutter isolate running: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background

```
dependencies:
  flutter_background: ^1.1.0
```